# cherrypy and Django: Is this possible?

Tags: django, static, wsgi, cherrypy

I was battling to find how my Django project will serve static files through cherrypy...Tried searching found so many solutions...didn't work...Then suddenly just by using cherrypy's wsgiserver and collectstatic from django everything worked....Is this right? Why does everyone  propose different solutions for this?

my server.py

```
__author__ = 'avlahop'
######################################################
#Trying to make cherrypie work with Django           #
######################################################


#needed for environ set and python path
import os
import sys

import cherrypy.wsgiserver as wsgiserver

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

from django.core.servers.basehttp import run, WSGIServerException
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

import rhombus
import rhombus.settings
#import webbrowser
import cherrypy

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'rhombus.settings'
app_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(app_dir))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'To exit close this window'
    app = WSGIHandler()
    server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(
        ('0.0.0.0', 8000),
        app,
        server_name='www.django.example',
        numthreads=20,
    )

    try:
        server.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop()
```

It is serving static files normally but i cannot access them. e.g if i try to access

```
http://mysite/static/main.css
```

where main css is in the static/ folder i get an error from django that it can find that nowhere in my urls.py. Could you explain to me is this normal behavour?

Comment: Why do you need to use two frameworks? I would avoid this if at all possible

Comment: I'm not using the whole cherrypy framework. Just the wsgiserver of cherrypy. I need django project to be installed in windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is information missing from your question. Such as how you have the rest of your application configured.

It is perfectly reasonable to use cherrypy as a webserver but your solution is not actually serving the files from where your collectstatic command is sending them. Are you running in "debug" mode.

Finally, is your goal to use this is production for a high volume site? (not a good idea) As a small low-volume in-house project?

Comment: you are right :). It didn't. But i fixxed it:). I made an application that takes the STATIC_ROOT of a django project and serves everythin under path STATIC_URL. Then I used the WSGIPathInfoDispatcher to dispatch it on cherrypy wsgiserver. Worked like a charm. I was based on the django-wsgiserver module. 
The project is not in-house is for production. But it will be deployed in windows. It is packaged using py2exe, in to an exe file that starts the cherrypy server.